# How AngularJS Module works?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is regarding How angularJS Module work

I have made a small bunch of code using AngularJS and I cannot understand the following things.

**Include angular js but not register module**

I included angularJS but never registered with the module. it gives me wrong output.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">

    <div>

        <p>{{1+2}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

**include angularJS and register with module**

Now, When I registered the angular application with the module. it runs and gives correct output.

```js
 var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myapp">

    <div>

        <p>{{1+2}}</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

My questions are...

1. How angular Works with the module?
2. Do I need to register it every time with my module?
3. What is the deep concept of AngularJS module?

Answer (score 0):

What is a Module?
You can think of a module as a container for the different parts of your app – controllers, services, filters, directives, etc.

Why?
Most applications have a main method that instantiates and wires together the different parts of the application.

AngularJS apps don't have a main method. Instead modules declaratively specify how an application should be bootstrapped. There are several advantages to this approach:

- The declarative process is easier to understand.
- You can package code as reusable modules.
- The modules can be loaded in any order (or even in parallel) because
  modules delay execution.
- Unit tests only have to load relevant modules, which keeps them fast.
- End-to-end tests can use modules to override configuration.

[More on angular module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs is pretty awesome. I just started learning it last Monday. It's not too difficult to pick up basic concepts, but admittedly my only experience so far is to create a bootstrap menu from the results of an API call.

For your specific questions:

1. You create the app in a separate js file then you load it in your html as a script. For example you create a file in a subdirectory to your `index.html`, `/src/myTestApp.js`, then you load it in your `index.html` using (can't seem to escape to code here... )script src="/src/myTestApp.js">

So basically,

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
```

initializes the base AngularJs module which you have called `app`.

2. You need to register every module that you would need, but after that you can call it anytime if it's in the same $scope. I think this is called dependency injection.
3. AngularJs is a JavaScript framework for front-end web development. It does especially well at creating single page applications (SPA). It uses the Model View Controller concept, where you separate the different layers of the code for better management/workflow. It has two-way data binding and a whole bunch of built in html directives that makes it very seamless to pull data from your model, pass it to your controller and display it on your view.

There's many more but these reasons I listed are the main reason I'm getting into it. It exactly fits the specifications and requirements I have for my next project.